# Console Writeline with threaded C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stream, console

Hello I am trying to make threaded system for my console applications console output.

I did the KonsolStream like that.

```
public class KonsolStream
{
    ManualResetEvent _pauseEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
    ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    Thread _thread;

    private string _yazi;
    private int _tip;

    public int _Tip
    {
        get => _tip;
        set => _tip = value;
    }
    public string _Yazi
    {
        get => _yazi;
        set => _yazi = value;
    }

    public void KonsolaYaz()
    {
        switch (_Tip)
        {
            case 1:
                //uyarı
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(_Yazi);
                Console.ResetColor();
                IstemciDurdur();
                break;
            case 2:
                //başarı
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine(_Yazi);
                Console.ResetColor();
                IstemciDurdur();
                break;
            case 3:
                //log
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine(_Yazi);
                Console.ResetColor();
                IstemciDurdur();
                break;
            default:
                IstemciDurdur();
                break;
        }
    }
    private void IstemciDurdur()
    {
        _pauseEvent.Reset();
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
        _thread.Start();
    }
    public void Resume()
    {
        _pauseEvent.Set();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _pauseEvent.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);

            if (_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
                break;

            KonsolaYaz();
        }
    }

}
public class KonsolMesaji : KonsolStream
{
    public KonsolMesaji(string yazi,int tip)
    {
        _Yazi = yazi;
        _Tip = tip;
    }
    public void Yaz()
    {
        Start();
    }
}
```

The Problem is when i start SistemBaslat()
The messages are not synchronous.
some times it starts with write message. and sometimes its start with Again
I want to make the KonsolStream like, When i want to write some output to console i will use this stream lateron.

Comment: Welcome to the world of multi-threading. Your messages are writing to the console in the order that the threads have been executed - just because your code looks linear in the SistemBaslat method you are creating threads & once you have started the thread you have no control over the order the individual threads will write to the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the order of the message to be kept, you will have to use only one thread reading a single queue and have all the other threads push data into it. The good news is that your code will be much simpler; the bad news is that you have to have access to the queue wherever you want to log (you may create a static logger to ease this).

Edit: Instead of giving you the code, I suggest you check this link: [Simple MultiThread Safe Log Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954900/simple-multithread-safe-log-class).
You should find all your answers.

Comment: Can you write me a simple solution about that. Also i can rewrite the whole code thats not problem i am at the start. I just want to make 4 threads for my program

Comment: The order of the message IS being kept - the writing is being done in the KonsolaYaz method which is called from the thread. Just because the string to write is set in the constructors & the threads started in a particular order - that does not guarantee the order of write. For your solution to work, the messages would have to be added to the queue in the constructor not in the KonsolaYaz event.

Answer (score 0):

When reading your question I'm asking myself: do you just want to know about that for academical reasons (i.e. to learn how logging in a multi-threaded system works) or do you actually want to have multi-threaded logging in a productive application later on?

If your answer is the latter I would suggest using [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) as this can give you exactly what you want with just a little of configuration.

**Update**
After looking at the problem again I agree with PaulF that there's still a need to tie the results of the threads together and then write the different buckets to the console sequentially.
In order to achieve this you could use a (static) instance of a class that holds all the logging messages for each thread (to distinguish the threads you can use the thread id as a key) and waits for the thread to finish, then writes all the log entries of this thread to the console sequentially.

Comment: isnt that a logger for webserver, thats apache one.

Comment: Because the console write is actually done in the threads from the KonsolaYaz method - then log4net would suffer the same issue. The problem is that @ErimVarış is thinking that because the string is set in the constructor & the threads are started in a particular order then the threads will be processed in a particular order. Unfortunately, once the SistemBaslat is exited - there is no guarantee which of the two threads will run the KonsolaYaz method first.

Comment: @ErimVarış: no it is also available for locally running programs.